# Change text color inside code function on Woocommerce

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to change the color to this part of the code:

```
'% discount'
```

(this will show the % of the amount plus the word Discount" but I need to use a particular color for this "% discount"

```
* Display the discount in payment method title.
 */
public function wpd_payment_method_title($title, $id) {
    if (!is_checkout() && !( defined('DOING_AJAX') && DOING_AJAX )) {
        return $title;
    }

    $settings = get_option('woo_payment_discounts_setting');
    $settings = maybe_unserialize($settings);
    if (isset($settings[$id]['amount']) && 0 < $settings[$id]['amount']) {
        $discount = $settings[$id]['amount'];
        if ($settings[$id]['type'] == 'percentage') {
            $value = $discount . '% discount';
        } else {
            $value = wc_price($discount);
        }
        $title .= ' <small>(' . sprintf(__('%s', 'woo-payment-discounts'), $value) . ')</small>';
    }
    return $title;
}
```

Any idea how to do this?

Actually it shows a black "% discount" word and I need it green. I know how to create a CSS class, but I don't know how to implement that to this code.
I'm sorry but I'm new on this. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
public function wpd_payment_method_title($title, $id) {
    if (!is_checkout() && !( defined('DOING_AJAX') && DOING_AJAX )) {
        return $title;
    }

    $settings = get_option('woo_payment_discounts_setting');
    $settings = maybe_unserialize($settings);
    if (isset($settings[$id]['amount']) && 0 < $settings[$id]['amount']) {
        $discount = $settings[$id]['amount'];
        if ($settings[$id]['type'] == 'percentage') {
            $value =  $discount . '<span style="color:green;">' . __('% discount', 'woo-payment-discounts') . '</span>';
        } else {
            $value = wc_price($discount);
        }
        $title .= ' <small>(' . sprintf(__('%s', 'woo-payment-discounts'), $value) . ')</small>';
    }
    return $title;
}
```

It should work.

---

If you want to have the discount percentage number in green too, you will use this instead:

```
$value = '<span style="color:green;">' . $discount . __('% discount', 'woo-payment-discounts') . '</span>';
```

---

Or you can add a class:

```
$value = '<span class="discount-color">' . $discount . __('% discount', 'woo-payment-discounts') . '</span>';
```

And on your theme's `styles.ccs` file you will addthe following rule:

```css
.discount-color {
    color:green;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so so much! Works great! :)